# OSError when loading JSON file in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to load a big JSON file in order to test an API.
It is pretty straight forward.

I include the libraries
Library    RequestsLibrary
Library    Collections
Library    JSONLibrary

The code in particular that is failing

${payload}=    Load Json From File    C:\Users\SVD\Desktop\VS Robots\api\sample1.json

Error code: OSError

I did check the file permission, everything is fine there. I even tried sample JSON files from the web.

Everything should be up to date as far as dependencies go.

Maybe it is good to put it out there I am using Visual Studio Code with the Robot Framework plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out issue was with the path ( go figure)

When I copy the path from Visual Studio it gives out this format C:\Users\SVD\Desktop\VS Robots\api\sample1.json

All I had to do is switch the \ with /